# Can't iterate through every child on Firebase

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to iterate through every child received in a data snapshot and put the key in a map. In the code snippet below, the execution seems to stop where I'm putting data in to the map.

```
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Fixtures").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.exists()) {

                long childcount = snapshot.getChildrenCount();

                    for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                        String currentuser = ds.getKey();
                        List<UserFixtures> emptyList = new ArrayList<>();
                        userPredictions.put(currentuser, emptyList);

                        childcount--;

                        if (childcount == 0) {
                            addFixturestoUserPredictions();
                        }

                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled (DatabaseError error){

        }
    });
```

So there are three children, but on the first iteration, execution stops after the map.put method. It doesn't crash, it just stops and doesn't even reach childcount--;. I have no idea what's going on.

The snapshot definitely contains all three children and their data.

This code is on Google App Engine.

Comment: can you share the logs ? And why are you adding empty list to map (List<UserFixtures> emptyList = new ArrayList<>();
                        userPredictions.put(currentuser, emptyList);)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.

I had declared my list as

```
Map<String, List<UserFixtures>> userPredictions
```

but I should have been...

```
Map<String, List<UserFixtures>> userPredictions = new HashMap<>();
```